# Copy same file multiple times into same destination folder in matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, matrix, copy

File name is 1.jpg and i have to copy this file 800 times into path 'F:\copiedimages' how it can be done in matlab.Same file should be copied 800 times into given path.

source code i tried:

```
for i=1:800
copyfile('1.jpg','F:\copiedimages/');
end
```

Comment: With different names each time?

Comment: @Dan ya with different names.

Comment: And what is the pattern of the names? 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc etc or 1_copy_1.jpg, 1_copy_2.jpg?

Comment: @Dan Only single file 1.jpg and it is replicated 800 times

Comment: @prshanth, yes and what will these new 800 files be called??? If try my solution I think you'll find that it does indeed copy 1 file into 800 new copies...

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your files new names. I'll go with the pattern `1 Copy (i).jpg` which you build up using string concatenation:

```
for i=1:800
    copyfile('1.jpg',['F:\copiedimages\1 Copy (', num2str(i), ').jpg']);
end
```